# Rect offset trouble android

Tags: android, canvas, rect

I have a rectangle that is having its x cord increased so it moves to the left. I need that when it reaches a specific point, say 300, it moves back to where it started and do this all over again. This way I want a warp effect. I am using this code:

```
Rect stripe= new Rect(x, 0,width+x, c.getHeight());

int a =stripe.left;

Log.d(T, String.valueOf(stripe.left));

if (a>300){
        a=-150;
         stripe.set(stripe.left+a,stripe.top,stripe.right+a,stripe.bottom );
    }
c.drawRect(stripe,verPaint);
```

The problem is even though I am moving it back 150, the left property does not change. So even though in the first time after hitting 300, the left should become 150, it still remains 300 and keeps on moving.

Could anyone provide me with a solution?

Comment: assuming your above code is in a method. Your stripe variable is local. Make it a class member rather than re creating everytime in  your method

Comment: ok.........any suggestions on the problem?